# Sync between locale files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have two languages yml files like en.yml and es.yml. Whenever i add some keys to en.yml i don't want to manually copy the strings from en.yml to es.yml. Is there any plugin which does this job or any rake command to do that ?

For example

```
en:
  key1: "Message1"
  key2: "Message2"

es:
  key1: "Message1"
```

When i run some job key2 must be attached to es.yml

Answer (score 1):

I just released a rails plugin, only tested on Rails 3 which helps you to keep locale files in sync providing 2 simple rake tasks.

It's available on github at https://github.com/eserra/localizator

Install with:

```
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/eserra/localizator.git
```

Since it's my first Rails plugin any feedback would be appreciated!

Hope it helps.